# Assign value to binding property in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have create controller where I create entry to database

Here is code

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
        [Bind("Title", "Date", "WorkTime", "Quantity", "ServiceId", "Price", "ProjectId", "WorkTimeTo", "CreatingDate", "WorkDoneFrom", "WorkDoneTo",
            "BreakFrom", "BreakTo")]
        Proposals proposal)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Proposals.Add(proposal);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["ServiceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Services, "Id", "Name",proposal.ServiceId);
        ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(_context.Projects, "Id", "Name", proposal.ProjectId);
        return View(proposal);
    }
```

But for property `WorkTime` I need to make DateTime.now value. How I can apply this to property correctly?

Comment: Assuming `WorkTime` property is of `DateTime` type, Just assign the property value before saving `proposal.WorkTime = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Yeah, that's it @Shyju